# Celery dont register periodic tasks

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-celery, celerybeat

I'm trying to run celery worker, but when i do that Celery can't see my periodic tasks for some reason.

Here is my console output:

```
------------- celery@andrey-MS-7996 v4.2.1 (windowlicker)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.15.0-39-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic 2018-12-03 13:49:13
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         sjimalka:0x7fa69bef3e48
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]


[2018-12-03 13:49:13,380: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2018-12-03 13:49:13,385: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2018-12-03 13:49:13,392: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-12-03 13:49:14,409: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-12-03 13:49:14,432: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/andrey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:200: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
[2018-12-03 13:49:14,433: INFO/MainProcess] celery@andrey-MS-7996 ready.
```

**init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sjimalka.settings')

app = Celery('sjimalka')

app.conf.timezone = 'Europe/Moscow'
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'delete_old_foos': {
        'task': 'main.tasks.delete_old_foos',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=5)
    },
}

redis_host = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost') 

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
```

main.tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
from django.utils import timezone
from main.models import image, imagenew, FtpPath
import os
from os import path as ospath
import datetime
from ftplib import FTP
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFile
import shutil
import piexif
import cv2 as cv

app = Celery()

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute='*/5'))
def delete_old_foos():
    imgs = image.objects.all()
    imgnews = imagenew.objects.all()

    for img in imgs:
        if img.delete_time < timezone.now() and img.deleted == False:
            image.objects.filter(pk=img.pk).update(deleted=True)
            try:
                os.remove('/home/andrey/sjimalka'+ img.image.url)
            except OSError:
                pass

    for imgnew in imgnews:
        if imgnew.delete_time < timezone.now() and imgnew.deleted == False:
            imagenew.objects.filter(pk=imgnew.pk).update(deleted=True)
            try:
                os.remove('/home/andrey/sjimalka'+ imgnew.image.url) 
            except OSError:
                pass

    shutil.rmtree('/home/andrey/sjimalka/media/archives/')
    os.chdir("/home/andrey/sjimalka/media/")
    os.mkdir('archives')

    return "completed deleting foos at {}".format(timezone.now())
```

Celery can't see task delete_old_foos and others, and I just can't understand why. Here is structure of my project: [structure](http://joxi.ru/krDwplBcEk8GqA). I didn't touch the project for 2 weeks, and it worked ok then. If I am running just simple celery-beat, it works fine. But workers just can't see tasks, and I can't see any errors yet. I running celery worker with:

```
celery -A sjimalka worker -l info -B
```